# Nested If Not Running Else

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to evaluate a couple of things.  I'm pasting the code from the first parent if statement and the nested if/else.  For some reason when a condition is met for the parent it always uses the nested if instead of going to the else.  Even if it does not meet the if criteria it still runs that piece of the code.

```
var setmeow = new Date();
var meow = nlapiDateToString(setmeow);
if(!Result[i].getValue('custcol_ram_billing_end_date') ){
    var edpb = Result[i].getValue('custcolram_last_rental_billed')
    if(edpb != null || edpb != ' ') {                       
        var daysbetwenced = days_between(nlapiStringToDate(Result[i].getValue('custcol_ram_billing_start_date')), setmeow);
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', daysbetwenced+1);
        //record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_ram_billing_start_date', Result[i].getValue('custcol_ram_billing_start_date'));
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_ram_billing_end_date', meow);
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcolram_last_rental_billed', meow);
    } else {
        var daysbetweennoend = days_between(nlapiStringToDate(Result[i].getValue('custcolram_last_rental_billed')), setmeow);
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', daysbetweennoend+1);
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_ram_billing_start_date', Result[i].getValue('custcolram_last_rental_billed'));
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_ram_billing_end_date', meow);
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcolram_last_rental_billed', meow);
    } 
}
```

Comment: i think you need `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Did you check the value of your variable edpb? Print it in the console and see what the value is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind that `||` is the logical-OR operator (kind-of),

```
if(edpb != null || edpb != ' ')
```

Whatever `edpb` is, it will **always** be either not equal to `null` or not equal to `' '`. That is, it will either be neither `null` nor `' '`, or else it will be one of them and not the other.

Maybe what you really want is to perform the `if` part if `edpb` is not either `null` or `' '`, which would be:

```
if (edpb != null && edpb != ' ')
```